# Why does a sed command work interactively but not in my script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line, sed

SED command not replacing in bash under Debian, but works in command line.

**Works in command line:**

```
sed -i 's|/dev/disk/by-label/SR6D4|/dev/disk/by-label/SR4D4|g' /etc/my/config.xml
```

**Not working in bash script, does not replace the string:**

```
from="SR6D4"
to="SR4D4"
path_from="/dev/disk/by-label/${from}"
path_to="/dev/disk/by-label/${to}"
echo "sed -i 's|${path_from}|${path_to}|g' $file"
sed -i 's|${path_from}|${path_to}|g' $file
```

Why doesn't replace string in file when using sed in bash?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Shell variables won't get expanded in single quotes. (It's kind of what single quotes are for.)

```
sed -i "s|${path_from}|${path_to}|g" "$file"
```

should work better. (I've added double quotes around `$file` just in case your filename ever contains spaces.)

Comment: Uh, very cheap error :) I did not notice, that I used simple quotes for sed :-( Of course double quotes are interpolated, while single are not. Thank you for pointing the error. Accepting as solution.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned earlier you have problem with quoting. But there are some opinions about string replacement in file. See below.

It's bad idea to replace string in file because it's unsafety. There is small probability to lost file's data while changing.

You could try to backup file before changing:

```
cp /path/to/file{,.backup}
sed -i 'place your pattern here' /path/to/file
```

and you will get file with name `file.backup`.

You need to remember: if your file will be damaged and you will delete and replace it - file will have different inode and will lost all hard links.

The second safety method:

```
mv /path/to/file{,.backup}; 
cat /path/to/file.backup | sed 'place your pattern here' > /path/to/file
```

---

The next point. As [bashFAQ thinks](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/021):

> Embedding shell variables in sed commands is never a good idea

Thats why you need to use `awk` with `-v` options instead. Your script may look like this:

```
from="SR6D4"
to="SR4D4"
path_from="/dev/disk/by-label/${from}"
path_to="/dev/disk/by-label/${to}"
sed -i 's|${path_from}|${path_to}|g' $file
mv $file{,.backup}
cat "${file}.backup" | awk -v awkfrom="$path_from" -v awkto="$path_to" '{gsub(awkfrom,awkto)}' > $file
```

Comment: Very detailed answer. But the OP was solved by the previous answer. So I select the other as solution.

Comment: @klor, yes, of course. I am only supplemented the answer of Ulrich Schwarz

Comment: Your answer however gave me the idea to make backup of changed files. Thus I vote to your answer.

Comment: BTW: where do I use shell variables? The script uses input arguments, but only locally, from command line. I don't see security risk here.

Comment: filenames can contain new line symbols or something else. This symbols must be handled safely.